# How to grant all privileges to a user? I failed to

Tags: mysql

These are my commands:

```
mysql> Grant all privileges on my_db to me@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user, host, Create_priv from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| user             | host      | Create_priv |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| root             | localhost | Y           |
| root             | ubuntu    | Y           |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | Y           |
| root             | ::1       | Y           |
|                  | localhost | N           |
|                  | ubuntu    | N           |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | Y           |
| me               | localhost | N           |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Well, we can see that 'me' still can't create tables.
Could you help me understand how to grant all privileges to me@'localhost'?

Comment: who are you when you're trying to grant privileges to `me`?

Comment: You must be logged on user who has all the privliges.

Comment: root in the OS != root in mysql

Comment: Well, I try this: 1) mysql -u root -p 2)  grant all on my_db.* to me@'localhost'; 3) flush privileges; 4) select create_priv from mysql.user where User='me'. And I can see that me has no privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grant ALL global-level privileges, use this query -

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Thank you to everybody. I seem to have progressed a bit.